# How do I get docusaurus to output non-markdown files in the autogenerated sidebar

Tags: docusaurus

I have a folder with a few `.md` files as well as some `.puml` and `.png` files.

I need to create a sidebar that contains links to all the files in the folder.

**Current Approach**

In `sidebar.js`

```
  diagramsSidebar: [
    {
      type: 'autogenerated',
      dirName: 'diagrams',
    },
  ]
```